# WP 5.3 Removing Default Wordpress Image Sizes

Tags: images, filters

I've found several [examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49332/how-to-prevent-upload-of-a-multiple-sizes-of-images/49338) where they use the `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` filter to unset the default WP image sizes that are generated whenever a user uploads a new image to the media library. This filter, on a brand new install with no plugins will not be called at all.

Calling `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` spits out the following array:

```
[05-Feb-2020 17:29:55 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => medium_large
    [3] => large
    [4] => 1536x1536
    [5] => 2048x2048
)
```

Where did 1536x1536 come from?
Where did 2048x2048 com from?

I later tried to call `remove_image_size('size')` from within an `init` action and this only worked for the two new sizes mentioned above. The other default sizes still remained:

```
[05-Feb-2020 17:30:26 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => medium_large
    [3] => large
)
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Has something changed?

Comment: Ive found another similar question regarding the new image sizes, apparently it's new since 5.3:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/354379/57775.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question also uses the `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` filter. This filter is not working for me.

Comment: note that some enterprise WP hosts remove all image sizes to prevent those files being created, and then use runtime URL parameters to get the sizes instead. WP VIP is known for this

Answer (score 7):

Using the `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` filter was not working for me. However, the `intermediate_image_sizes` works and the `$default_sizes` array is an indexed array, not an associative array. In every single example that I have found for using the `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` filter, the answer's are unsetting the image sizes from an associative array.

The following worked for me in WP 5.3:

```php
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'remove_default_img_sizes', 10, 1);

function remove_default_img_sizes( $sizes ) {
  $targets = ['medium', 'medium_large', 'large', '1536x1536', '2048x2048'];

  foreach($sizes as $size_index=>$size) {
    if(in_array($size, $targets)) {
      unset($sizes[$size_index]);
    }
  }

  return $sizes;
}
```

[Here's a link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L4449) to the function that adds the two additional sizes since 5.3 with an explanation to why I was able to remove them using `remove_image_size`.

Comment: This solution worked for me where `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` was not.

Answer (score 0):

In addition: the  `1536x1536` and `2048x2048` sizes are not removed by the `intermediate_image_sizes`-filter. To remove them, I just use the `remove_image_size`-method.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_remove_default_additional_image_sizes' );
function wpdocs_remove_default_additional_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size( '1536x1536' );
    remove_image_size( '2048x2048' );
}
```

(from: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_add_additional_image_sizes/#comment-6722)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can used below code to remove image sizes is placed in the appropriate location within your theme or plugin.

`after_setup_theme` action hook used to achieve functionality.

```
function remove_default_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size('thumbnail');
    remove_image_size('medium');
    remove_image_size('medium_large');
    remove_image_size('large');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_default_image_sizes');
```